# Accessing server with its own public key

Tags: php, ssh

I am using ssh2_connect() in PHP to move files from one server to another. However for the time being there are not two servers and I am just connecting the server to itself.

This is setup so that when there are two servers only the connection information needs changing rather than converting everything to ssh2 from the standard PHP functions.

This has worked for a while using password authentication but I am now switching over to Public Key authorisation.

I get the following error when trying to connect:

```
Username/PublicKey combination invalid
```

I've setup up the key a couple of times and the same thing happens. I am now wondering if it is not possible to authenticate this way on the same machine?

I know everything else is working with ssh because I have accessed the server with a public key from another server for another purpose.

Comment: Does the key work on the command line?

Comment: maybe php uses wrong user for the key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit: Cleared things up. I assume you use a Debian based distro like Ubuntu, so details might differ in your case.**

It might be because you switched methods from password to key based. Things to do:

1. Delete all content of your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file. This is because it stores a fingerprint for all successfull connections you had before. If you change your method of access, you should delete either the line with the fingerprint of the old connection or empty the whole file to be safe.
2. Activate the home key folder in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by uncommenting the line

   ```
   AuthorizedKeysFile      %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
   ```
3. Generate a key pair without a passphrase via `ssh-keygen -t rsa`. Do not enter a passphrase.
4. Make sure both key files (id_rsa and id_rsa.pub) are in `~/.ssh/`
5. Add the public key to your authorized_keys via `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (Maybe adjust to your keyname).
6. Make sure the permissions of ~/.ssh/ look like this:

   ```
   drwx------  2 user user 4096 Oct 20 17:41 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 20 user user 4096 Nov  6 10:29 ../
   -rw-------  1 user user 1228 Oct 20 17:41 authorized_keys
   -rw-------  1 user user 1679 Oct 20 17:41 id_rsa
   -rw-------  1 user user  394 Oct 20 17:41 id_rsa.pub
   -rw-------  1 user user  984 Oct 20 17:41 known_hosts
   ```
7. Restart the ssh server. This can for example be done via `sudo service ssh restart`. You can check if it's running via `sudo lsof -i -P | grep -i sshd`
8. Do a manual log in the first time before using php, because there might be a prompt asking if you are trusting the host. You will have to answer by typing yes.

You can force ssh to use a certain key file either with the -i option or by configuring a shortcut in the `/etc/ssh_config`. You can also force it to disable password-based authentication by using `-o PasswordAuthentication=no`

Example:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@127.0.0.1
```

Comment: `ssh user@ip` from the commandline. Maybe `ssh user@localhost` or `ssh user@127.0.0.1` works as well.

Comment: How can I force it to use a public key though, I haven't yet turned off password auth and need to keep it on, also do I have to specify which public key to use otherwise the root key will be used.

Comment: so I am using  ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@1.2.3.4 to login using the right public key but when I enter the keys passphrase it says permission denied.

Comment: If you want to use it over a php script in the end anyway,  you should use a key without a passphrase.  Check `man ssh_config` , there is a settung called PasswordAuth or similar.  You should turn that off with the -o argument. I am on my phone right now,  i will post an example when im home.

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: thanks for that, I am using Centos by the way. On point 2 what does %h mean I am currently using an authorized_keys file in the root folder will that not be affected by this change?

Comment: I have followed those steps and I'm getting - "Host key verification failed"

Comment: this is were it goes wrong (viewing the login attempt in verbose mode) debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY

Comment: It said prior to that The authenticity of host ... ...can't be established - but I'm assuming that is normal for the first login?

Comment: At this point I would have to admit it would be just error googleing and t&e for me as well...things I would try: use the public ip, posting your ssh_config and the sshd_config

Comment: I just tried my setup successfully for myself. I just had another idea: are you using this to connect to your root user from your root user?

Comment: no they are different users

Comment: ok, so you are using this to connect *from* the user you are logged in as *to* the user you are logged in as, right? because this variant works for me. you could post your `/etc/ssh_config` and your `/etc/sshd_config`

Comment: An issue I discovered from the PHP ssh2 manual is that Apache needs to be able to read the key files so the permissions or ownership of the files needs to change from the default setting.